# Are there any libraries that have keyup/keypress keyCode normalization code?

Tags: javascript, dom, keyboard, dom-events

I'm looking for something that essentially codifies the browser weirdnesses listed here: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html and http://www.javascripter.net/faq/keycodes.htm into a library I can use in javascript. Preferably it would have some kind of interface like this:

```
domNode.addEventListener("keyup",function(e) {
  if(SuperKeys(e.which) === SuperKeys.down) {
    // do some down action
  }
})
```

It would also be nice if there was some way to easily convert between keypress keyCodes and keyup/keydown keycodes (with the appropriate shift key modifier).

It seems jquery has some normalization code: http://api.jquery.com/event.which/ . But, I'm looking for a tiny specialized module I can add to my code (I don't want to add jquery for this).

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: I suppose given that no one has answered, the answer is probably that there isn't any such library! Count me surprised

Answer (score 0):

I think http://jonathan.tang.name/files/js_keycode/ might do what you're looking for.

Side note: It looks like all jQuery does for `which` is this:

```
if (!event.which) {
  event.which = event.charCode != null ? event.charCode : event.keyCode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a year of nothing, I created the [keysight module](https://github.com/fresheneesz/keysight) to make dealing with keyboard events much easier. Example:

```
 domNode.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if(keysight(event).key === 'down') {
       // do some down action
    }
 })
```